# Docker unable to prepare context within directory

Tags: docker, semaphore-ci

So! I'm setting up a CI/CD system which has it's own folder and yaml file. Within that folder, I need to call docker build.  However, I continue to get 
the following error:

`unable to prepare context: path "./server" not found`.

**Here's the structure of my app:**

```
├──CI Folder
|   ├── deployment-file.yaml
├──server
|   ├── Dockerfile.prod
|   └── All the other files for building the server
```

Within the deployment-file.yaml, I'm calling:

`docker build -t dizzy/dizzy-server:latest -f ./server/Dockerfile.prod ./server`

I've tried every variation of this with relative paths like ../server, etc, but Docker won't take it.  It gives me a new error of `unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat`.

What's the proper way to do this or am I required to move that deployment-file.yaml to the root directory...

Comment: Looks like it is not able to find the docker file - I assume you have also tried docker build -t dizzy/dizzy-server:latest -f ../server/Dockerfile.prod ../server.

Comment: Yup!  Tried that one @Ajjo  that's when I get the symlink error.  `unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /Users/dizzy/Desktop/development/server/Dockerfile: no such file or directory`

Comment: Correction @Ajjo I tried it again and it works!  However, when the CI tries to do it..it doesn't.  I must be in some other context it doesn't understand because it says: <docker stuff here> ../client/Dockerfile.prod ../client
unable to prepare context: path "../client" not found.   Might be an issue on CI side or my misunderstanding rather than strictly docker's fault.